# Not able to run appium script on real device. getting a bad app error

Tags: java, android, appium, ui-automation

I am trying to execute this java code in eclipse, Using Appium and a real    device connected using USB. I am unable to lauch the test in the device for an app installed in the device.

```
    package appiumproject;
    import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.net.MalformedURLException;
    import java.net.URL;
    import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
    import org.openqa.selenium.remote.CapabilityType;
    import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

    public class StartApplication {

            private static AndroidDriver driver;
            public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, InterruptedException {

                File classpathRoot = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
                File appDir = new File(classpathRoot, "/sdcard/Android/data/");
                File app = new File(appDir, "com.alensw.PicFolder");

                DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
                capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "");
                capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "BX9034M10V");
                capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "4.1.2");
                capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
                capabilities.setCapability("app", app.getAbsolutePath());
                capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "com.alensw.PicFolder");
                //capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", "com.amazon.mShop.home.HomeActivity");

                driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
                driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(80, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                Thread.sleep(10000);
                driver.quit();
```

**And following is the error I am getting in eclipse console. Can somebody let me know the reason of error : 'Bad app'
How do I give the classPathRoot of app, appActivity from the android device?**
            }Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: A new session could not be created. (Original error: Bad app: C:\Users\admin\workspace\AppiumProject\sdcard\Android\data\com.alensw.PicFolder. App paths need to be absolute, or relative to the appium server install dir, or a URL to compressed file, or a special app name. cause: Error: Using local app, but didn't end in .zip, .ipa or .apk) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
    Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds
    Build info: version: '3.3.1', revision: '5234b32', time: '2017-03-10 09:04:52 -0800'
    System info: host: 'ADMIN-PC', ip: '10.0.0.63', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_121'
    Driver info: driver.version: AndroidDriver
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:216)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:168)
        at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumProtocolHandShake.createSession(AppiumProtocolHandShake.java:160)
        at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumProtocolHandShake.createSession(AppiumProtocolHandShake.java:75)
        at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.doExecute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:111)
        at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.execute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:162)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:604)
        at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.execute(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:42)
        at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:1)
        at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.execute(AndroidDriver.java:1)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:244)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:144)
        at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:38)
        at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.(AppiumDriver.java:88)
        at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.(AppiumDriver.java:112)
        at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.(AndroidDriver.java:73)
        at appiumproject.StartApplication.main(StartApplication.java:29)

```
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In the below capability you need to mention the path of .apk file

```
capabilities.setCapability("app", app.getAbsolutePath());
```

It should be like below:

```
capabilities.setCapability("app","path of apk file");
```

Comment: I just tried this  capabilities.setCapability("app", "/sdcard/Android/data/"); still the same error , @SaiPawan

Comment: add .apk file name at the end like "/sdcard/Android/data/sample.apk"

Comment: or else keep that apk file on desktop and give that path